# Suspicious return code when loading simple kernel module

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04

I wrote a simple hello world kernel module which looks like this:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static void hello_init(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "TEST: Hello world kernel \n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "TEST: Goodbye world!!1\n");
    return 0;
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

and this is my Makefile

```
obj-m += hello.o

KDIR = /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

I loaded the module using insmod hello.ko and the output of dmesg is:

```
    [ 4203.339976] TEST: Hello world kernel 
[ 4203.339985] do_init_module: 'hello'->init suspiciously returned 25, it should follow 0/-E convention
[ 4203.339985] do_init_module: loading module anyway...
[ 4203.339991] CPU: 0 PID: 7037 Comm: insmod Tainted: PF          O 3.11.0-19-generic #33~precise1-Ubuntu
[ 4203.339993] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[ 4203.339995]  00000000 00000000 f457dee0 c1673634 f8633000 f457df04 c166a007 c1901418
[ 4203.340001]  c169475c f863300c 00000019 c169475c f457df60 f8633000 f457df3c c10bb1d8
[ 4203.340006]  00000000 ffff8000 00007fff c10b8ce0 00000a02 f457df60 08b9c008 f457df68
[ 4203.340011] Call Trace:
[ 4203.340022]  [<c1673634>] dump_stack+0x41/0x52
[ 4203.340026]  [<c166a007>] do_init_module+0xfc/0x1c6
[ 4203.340033]  [<c10bb1d8>] load_module+0x358/0x520
[ 4203.340036]  [<c10b8ce0>] ? show_initstate+0x50/0x50
[ 4203.340036]  [<c10bb44b>] SyS_init_module+0xab/0xf0
[ 4203.340036]  [<c168540d>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
```

What's wrong with that "suspicious ..." message (there's a return 0 in init!) and why it's a Call trace printed ?
shouldn't just the hello alert be printed ?
FYI: i'm using 3.11.0-19-generic from a fresh vbox installation of ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Related: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/cloud-and-networking/9781789953435/5/ch05lvl1sec13/the-0-e-return-convention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this type definition instead:

```
static int __init hello_init(void)

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
```

Comment: that's right! Not sure what i was thinking to return 0 on a static void function :) thank you

Comment: BTW, if you passed the `-Wall` flag to `gcc` you'll have been warned.